# Calculate accuracy of crowdsourced responses in realtime

Tags: sampling

I have a total dataset of, lets say, 1000 Items. Each item will get a response from the crowd.

After I get all the 1000 responses, I can sample the dataset to calculate accuracy. Sampling would involve checking the responses for items and comparing it with our own knowledge.

Eg: If the task was to tag images as `T-Shirts` and `Jeans`. Out of 1000 responses, I can sample a few and open the images and see what they are, and then compare them with the response that I got from the crowd.

**But how can I calculate the accuracy of the total dataset in real-time, as the responses are being submitted?**